# Some key combinations are not available for user applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

I'm using GUI text editor SciTE and I want to use the following key combinations for selecting rectangular regions of text in SciTE: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>.

It appears that I can do it in Linux Mint, but I can not get it to work in Debian.
Debian blocks these keys.
I want to know how to make these keys available for user applications.

My systems:

- Linux Mint 18, MATE 1.14.1
- Debian 8.7 (jessie), MATE 1.8.1

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> for switching keyboard layout (English-Russian) on both my systems.
And I'd like it to stay that way (because of my "finger memory").

What I have tried:
I opened `dconf-editor` and changed everywhere `mouse-button-modifier` from `<Alt>` to `<Super>`, and disabled all key combinations at all, then restarted Linux.
That did not solve my problem.

Interesting detail:
When I use VirtualBox (host = Debian, guest = Linux Mint), `Alt-Shift-Up/Down` key combinations work inside guest system!

---

`xev` output for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> on Linux Mint:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1272551, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1273025, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x18, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1273538, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x19, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1273605, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x19, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1274384, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x19, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 1274824, (42,42), root:(465,335),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

`xev` output for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> on Debian:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13862445, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13862855, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x18, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 13862856, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 13862857, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 13862857, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 13862858, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13863422, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x2018, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13863489, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x2018, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13864456, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x2018, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 13864793, (48,45), root:(85,108),
    state 0x2018, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

`xev` output for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> on Linux Mint:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 3118153, (47,39), root:(78,133),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 3118245, (47,39), root:(78,133),
    state 0x18, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 3118377, (47,39), root:(78,133),
    state 0x19, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x1c4 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 3118380, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x1c4 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 3118382, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x1c4 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 3118383, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x1c4 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 3118385, state PropertyNewValue

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x3c00002, time 3118535, (47,39), root:(78,133),
    state 0x2018, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

`xev` output for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> on Debian:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 16284126, (36,50), root:(76,134),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 16284503, (36,50), root:(76,134),
    state 0x18, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 16284506, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 16284506, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 16284507, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    atom 0x1c0 (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 16284507, state PropertyNewValue

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 16284786, (36,50), root:(76,134),
    state 0x2018, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x4000002, time 16285071, (36,50), root:(76,134),
    state 0x2018, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

As you can see, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> key combination is processed differently:

- on Debian keyboard layout is switched on key PRESS,
- on Linux Mint keyboard layout is switched on key RELEASE.

Sequence:

```
ALT pressed
SHIFT pressed
(at this moment Debian switches layout)
SHIFT released
(at this moment Linux Mint switches layout)
ALT released
```

Probably, this is the reason why <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> does not work on Debian.

**How can I make <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> coexist with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> on Debian?**

Comment: Fedora with KDE Plasma has the same issue. I didn't find a solution just yet. :(